# Assign width to elements according to screen size in Android

Tags: android

I have the below views in a RelativeLayout in my activity.xml:

```
> <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/clr_title"
>         android:layout_width="@dimen/Que_text"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
>         android:text="TextView" />
> 
>     <Spinner
>       android:id="@+id/clr_spinner"
>       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
>       android:layout_width="@dimen/Que_spinner"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
>       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clr_title" />
```

this means that my views are one next to the other. I have assigned dynamic width (using dimens.xml).

I am testing o a Galaxy Tab 3 (8" 1280x800) and a Nexus 5 (5" 1920x1080).
i want the width of the TextView to be 200dp on Nexus and 500dp on Galaxy tab in order to be visible to both devices.

What folders should i create to assign the width according to the screen size?
Can i create a "values" folder based on inches?

Comment: Maybe you'd best read [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and then try the "smallest width" approach or you provide several layouts based on "width". Or just parts of layouts. One can reuse parts by using "include" in the layout xml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have to follow  dimensions in values folder

`values (normal phones)          eg:1dp
 values-large(7 inch Tablets)    eg:1.5dp
 values-xlarge(10 inch Tablets)  eg:2dp`

each dimensions will be differ for  `values`, `values-large`, `values-xlarge`